# Visual Studio 2012 syntax coloring for C# types

Tags: syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get user type C# syntax highlighting working again in VS 2012 RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970305/how-can-i-get-user-type-c-sharp-syntax-highlighting-working-again-in-vs-2012-rc)

I have installed VS 2012 on a system that previously had VS 2010. Now syntax coloring doesn't color the type names (classes, interfaces) in C#. I can't find the setting to define the type colors in the Tools options.

I did another fresh install on a VM and there it works well.

Comment: Wait, are you asking about changing colors in 2010 or 2012?

Comment: In VS2010 the Text Editor item is called `User Types`.

Comment: Same issue. `User types` entry is missing the text editor color options in VS 2012.

Comment: Yes, that other question solved my issue, thanks.

Comment: Uninstalling 2012RC Web Express works well for me :) stackoverflow.com/questions/12197771/