# No syntax highlighting or intellisense for C# files in VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've just installed the RTM version of VS2012 Premium from MSDN (11.0.50727.1).  I have created an C# ASP.NET MVC 4 application, and a C# console application, but neither give me syntax highlighting or Intellisense for the following file types:

- cs
- cshtml

BUT all other file types seem to work fine, including:

- html
- js
- XML
- CSS
- config

I am running on Windows 7, virtualized in VMWare Fusion 5, on Mac OSX Lion.  I also have VS 2010 installed in the same VM, which has and still does run fine.

I have tried running devenv.exe /setup with no success.

I have tried Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset with no success.

Anyone got any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found I also had Visual Studio 2012 Web Express RC installed.  When I uninstalled this, C# intellisense and syntax highlighting magically started to work.

Comment: Same here, though I've had Ultimate RC installed.

Answer (score 2):

I found I had to run

```
devenv /resetuserdata
```

I chose not to import from previous versions. I had to re-enter all my TFS connections but now my app.config is in color in VS2012.

Comment: This worked for me, in my case syntax highlight just stopped working for .cshtml files