# VS2012 Text Editor colors with Windows Domain User

Tags: colors, themes, visual-studio-2012, text-editor

I'm having problem with the text editor. I see all text colors right but 'Classes words' in black instead of light-blue.

I've tried resetting all settings, changing between dark and light theme, importing correct working settings, with no success. I've also tried repairing VS installation.

I'm logged in with an Administrator Domain User. When I log in with a local user, I have no problem with the colors.

I'm using VS2012 RTM and Windows8RTM. Thanks.

Comment: Have you changed any settings for coloring in VS12? Or do you run the default values?

Comment: No, I always use default values!

Comment: I'm on a Win8 and will install VS12 next week so I'm very interested in how this can be approached. Are you saying that the colors are **completely** missing or is it only the classes that aren't highlighted? If the first is true, we'll be looking for enabling a language definition. If the second, we'll be scratching our heads for references to those classes being gone. Which is it?

Comment: Only the user types (classes) which default color is light-blue. It's very strange because I have no problem with local users and I've also reinstalled VS.

Comment: I don't think it's got to do with VS. I think it's got to do with .NET definitions. Apparently, VS doesn't recognize the classes when you're logged in as admin. It means (I suspect) that it can't access the Framework. (1) Can you compile or do you get errors? (2) If you declare your own, static class and then refer to it - is it still black or does **that** color it blue?

Comment: By any measures it rates high on my weird-shit-o-meter!

Comment: Ja! The problem is when I'm logged in with a DOMAIN user (also admin). Local users or local admin user are ok. (1) I can compile, run applications, and other normal tasks. (2) It's still black!

Comment: I don't think you're going to like my reply but I don't have a clue as to why the duck you're having that issue (typo intended). I had some ideas but apparently, it's none of them. One thing is sure - I'm not switching to VS12 next week, hehe. Perhaps you should ask this question on SuperUser? It's more of a config-matter than coding matter... Just make sure to put it at-sign and my signature so I'll get notifications too. Good luck. You're gonna need it... Would you like **me** to ask it for you? You're new to SO, I see and stuff can be unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: I would be grateful if you do that for me. Thanks!

Comment: Please tell me when you ask the question on SuperUser. Will I receive notifications? Thank you!

Comment: I've re-posted your question there. You can go to [this page](http://superuser.com/questions/484632/vs2012-text-editor-colors-missing-with-windows-domain-user) to view it. You will probably be asked to log onto Super User and link your accounts. That's OK - you want that. Then you'll have two linked accounts. One on SO and one on SU.

Comment: Great! Let's pray for a solution, now I'm feeling that I'm programming in the notepad, hehe.

Comment: Haha, good one. Did you register for SU, yet? Also, when you said Notepad - are you saying that **all** code beautification is gone or just the class names?

Comment: Yes I did. No, only the class names, but for me it's like the notepad.

Comment: Sure - I don't mean that it's not so bad because it's **only** classes that are gone. But it means it's some hick-up with libraries (or class definitions) and not a general code beautification being ducked up. (typo intended)    Sadly, it looks like you're going to get the badge for tumbleweed...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970305/how-can-i-get-user-type-c-sharp-syntax-highlighting-working-again-in-vs-2012-rc/12792004#12792004

Matt's answer solved my problem!!!

Comment: Cool! I'll past a link to that discussion as an answer, so it's searchable by Google and others. Check my answer as correct (green checky thing **BUT** do not set a grade up on me, since I didn't find the solution. Instead, go to that Matt character and grade him up. He'll be surely pleased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple suggestions can be found in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970305/how-can-i-get-user-type-c-sharp-syntax-highlighting-working-again-in-vs-2012-rc/12792004#12792004).