# Visual Studio 2013 - User types color is gone

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Just installed Visual Studio 2013 (it seems there was no choice - tried to download vs 2012 from Microsoft but they automatically redirect me to 2013...).

I noticed that all those things that used to be colored in turquoise - like classes, types, attributes - are now plain black! I mean all those things that trigger the little blue "smart tag" thingie that when you press ctrl+dot you get a little option to add the appropriate "using" statement.[image]

I've looked through and through in the tools > options > fonts and colors. In vs 2012, under "display items", there were entries such as "user types - XXXXX" which were colored turquoise. But in 2013 they're gone too! :-(

Productivity power tools is not installed...

Anyone?

Comment: At my friend's computer, he has VS 2013 *ULTIMATE* and I have Professional, and for him this works perfectly... Does anyone know if this is the cause?

Comment: Don't know about 2013. However, you can still download 2012 - see https://www.google.co.il/search?q=download+visual+studio+2012 or http://search.microsoft.com/en-us/DownloadResults.aspx?q=visual+studio+2012.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get user type C# syntax highlighting working again in VS 2012 RC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970305/how-can-i-get-user-type-c-sharp-syntax-highlighting-working-again-in-vs-2012-rc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue in VS2013, fixed that with devenv.exe /setup

See 
[How can I get user type C# syntax highlighting working again in VS 2012 RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970305/how-can-i-get-user-type-c-sharp-syntax-highlighting-working-again-in-vs-2012-rc)

Answer (score 8):

For others who run into this, where the accepted answer doesn't work: try closing your project and deleting your suo file.

I tried devenv.exe /setup (as an admin, in a VS command prompt), I tried changing and restoring themes, I tried rebooting, etc.  Nothing worked, but deleting my suo file fixed it.

Comment: thank you! nothing worked for me either... did everything... only this worked

Comment: It might also happen for a single file, if its build action is not set to `Compile`

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the preview of Roslyn, unintstall it. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling and then enabling Productivity Power Tools 2013 extension resolved the issue for me.