# Lost formatting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've lost all the color formatting in the source view in Visual Studio and can't get it back. I tried to import a new scheme but nothing helps.

Anyone?

[image: source view in Visual Studio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this a while ago, these steps fixed it for me.

- close all running instances of Visual Studio
- open a "Run" window and type in devenv /resetuserdata

*edit*

perhaps this might work for you, its for 2012 but it might work for 2013

Here is a simple solution. Go to the directory where devenv is (for 2012 RC), and type devenv.exe /setup. It will fix your problem.

devenv.exe is usually in something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE.

Edit: It has been suggested that you do this from the Visual Studio command prompt (Start>Microsoft Visual Studio>Tools>Visual Studio Command Prompt), and/or make sure your command prompt has administrator permissions.

[How can I get user type C# syntax highlighting working again in VS 2012 RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970305/how-can-i-get-user-type-c-sharp-syntax-highlighting-working-again-in-vs-2012-rc)

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick!

```
devnev.exe /ResetSettings
```

More details here
[Lost formatting in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605106/lost-formatting-in-visual-studio/23605514?noredirect=1#23605514)