# visual studio 2013 update 4 - javascript highlithning stopped work

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

i am using "VisualStudio 2013 Update 4 (CommunityEdition)" everything works fine till last week.
Then i noticed that my JavaScript highlighting stopped working which is embedded in my HTML code.

It works fine and I never had problems before. Till last week, then it suddenly stopped working :/
I don't know why... i didn't changed something on my computer (no updates, no new software, no hardware upgrades) - it just stopped working :(

This thinks I try to solve the issue:

- every step did in this thread
  [How can I get user type C# syntax highlighting working again in VS 2012 RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970305/how-can-i-get-user-type-c-sharp-syntax-highlighting-working-again-in-vs-2012-rc/11003979#11003979)
- reinstalled VS2013
- reopened my project  and  created a new project

Nothing solved the problem... it still don't work...

At the moment i really frustrated, because i don't know why it stopped working and i don't know what i should try else to fix this problem...

Maybe somebody had the same problem and can epxlain me what i can check to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance,
vipex

Comment: Is there perhaps a syntax error in the file? Is this happening on all files or just one?

Comment: No there is no error in the synthax.

Comment: I checked the synthax 20x. Also it don't work in other files where it works before. I made a test and copied a JavaScript code from the internet into a new html file to my VS2013 - the highlithning also don't work...

Answer (score 0):

Today I checked my code (which isn't working in VS2013) with notepad++.
In notepad++ the JavaScript highlithning works fine. When i open this files in VS2013 the highlithning doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by installing the Visual Studio extension 'Web Essentials 2013 for Update 4'.

You can grab it from here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361