# Visual Studio, How to change the color of classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to change the color of the classes in the text editor. I am using Visual Studio and C#. I've been able to change all the other colors, but I can't find the options for classes.

Comment: You're probably looking for the *"User Types"* color setting

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Navigate to **Tools -> Options / Environment -> Fonts and Colors**. Change the color for "User Types - Classes".

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SeLaSXD.png]

(Despite being named "User Types", this setting applies to all classes.)

Comment: Also, when I made changes they did not show up until I did this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970305/how-can-i-get-user-type-c-sharp-syntax-highlighting-working-again-in-vs-2012-rc

Comment: Also... Resharper apparently overrides settings that already exist. So if you have Resharper, the setting to change is: Options / Environment->Fonts and Colors-ReSharper Class Identifier. :(

Comment: P.S: Sometimes you have to restart VS in order to see the changes

Comment: Answer is still valid in VS 2019.