# How do I set font colors for C# code in Visual Studio 2017 Community?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fonts, colors, color-scheme

Firstly, I've been using Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio 2017 for C# code. In VS Code, it's much easier to get themes as you can just download them but for VS 2017, you have to go through this behemoth and set change each one separately. [Fonts and Colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGwWP.png)

I want to make my VS 2017 as close to VS Code as possible. Currently my VS Code has the Monokai Pro theme installed. I'd like to know which items to change from VS 2017 in order to achieve the same colors as VS Code. Here are example pictures, basically I want the bottom image to look like the top one.

[Example VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UurVC.png)

[Example VS 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNkZF.png)

Sorry if I said something wrong I'm new to stackoverflow and I've looked a lot but couldn't find an answer or guide

Comment: Here's, could be an answer to you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014586/visual-studio-how-to-change-the-color-of-classes

Answer (score 0):

There has got to be a better way! There is a better way, use the [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor).

This theme looks to be close or you could at least import and use as a starting point:

https://studiostyl.es/schemes/litle-monokai-vstudio