# Is there any extension to edit Visual Studio (2017/2019) theme colors easily

Tags: visual-studio

So, I was wondering if someone knows a program (VS extension) that you can for example, click on a button (aka option), than you select what element (in your code) you want to edit, pick a new color and save it...?
eg. you click on void, it says something like, selected Data Types, and a window to edit color. Or you click on a scroll bar, it says something like, selected scroll bar, and so one..

I was looking for it, but all I can find is basically like "Color picker", "Color theme editor for Visual Studio"...

Even if it's not extension, maybe program or web site...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK... So there **is** some way to make it easier, but it's still quite boring / hard / annoying task to do. (Works only with Visual Studio 2019)

1. Download [Visual Studio Color Theme Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner).
2. You'll need some sort of capturing technique (eg. Snipping Tool - comes with Windows 10).
3. Launch your VS2019 and capture element/color you want to edit.
4. Extract the hex value of that color (eg. Paint 3D - comes with Windows 10).
5. Follow the instructions on VSCTD website (Marketplace) on creating theme and when you're done with opening solution, in "All elements" page, paste the value you got, and to make it easier to search, select "Sort by: Color".
6. Edit the color you think corresponds to desired element and check if that's the color that you were looking for.
7. Repeat until you're done.

This method is similar to using [Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2019ColorThemeEditor), but it gives you option to create automatically some theme and then you edit small parts of it (removes the trouble of editing huge amounts of colors)

Answer (score -1):

You can edit color themes for types of keywords for a language in Visual Studio. For example, I've set mine so that interfaces are a light purple instead of the normal blue.

As far as I know, you can't set the colors for a specific object (like have variable 1 in orange, and variable 2 in gray), but you can set the font colors for code types (so structs are orange, and classes are gray).

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014586/visual-studio-how-to-change-the-color-of-classes).

Comment: if you have installed "Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio", then you can edit almost any color in VS you like... the problem is, IT TAKES A LOOONG TIME to do it...